# I want a modal pop after the song ends in default audio player can any one help me with code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio, popup

below is my modal i want this to open automatically once the song gets over in default audio player

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel"
    aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
                    &times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">
                    Don't Wait, Login now!</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-8" style="border-right: 1px dotted #C2C2C2;padding-right: 30px;">
                        <!-- Nav tabs -->
                        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                            <li class="active"><a href="#Login" data-toggle="tab">Login</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#Registration" data-toggle="tab">Registration</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <!-- Tab panes -->
                        <div class="tab-content">
                            <div class="tab-pane active" id="Login">
                                <form role="form" class="form-horizontal">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">
                                        Email</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email1" placeholder="Email" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="col-sm-2 control-label">
                                        Password</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="password" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">
                                            Submit</button>
                                        <a href="javascript:;">Forgot your password?</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                            <div class="tab-pane" id="Registration">
                                <form role="form" class="form-horizontal">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="email" id="namea" class="col-sm-2 control-label">
                                        Name</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                                <select class="form-control">
                                                    <option>Mr.</option>
                                                    <option>Ms.</option>
                                                    <option>Mrs.</option>
                                                </select>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-9">
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="email" id="emailField" class="col-sm-2 control-label">
                                        Email</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtEmail" placeholder="Email" <input type="text"   />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="mobile" class="col-sm-2 control-label">
                                        Mobile</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                                        <input type="text" id="txtPhoneNo" class="form-control" id="mobile" placeholder="Mobile" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="password" id="p1" class="col-sm-2 control-label">
                                        Password</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                                        <input type="password" id="pass1" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                 <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="password"  class="col-sm-2 control-label">
                                       Re-Enter Password</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                                        <input type="password" id="pass2" class="form-control" id="password1" placeholder="Password" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-10">                             

                                        <button type="button" onclick="ValidateName();myFunction();ValidateNo();checkEmail();" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" >
                                            Save & Continue</button>
                                        <button type="button"  class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
                                            Cancel</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="OR" class="hidden-xs">
                            OR</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="row text-center sign-with">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <h3 class="other-nw">
                                    Sign in with</h3>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
                                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Facebook</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">
                                        Google +</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Login And Register  -->


<!-- Java scripts  -->

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".pop").click(function () {
            $("#myModal").modal();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: by `default audio player` you mean html5 audio player? answer can totally change based on the audio player.

Comment: @CerlinBoss yes its  html5 audio player

Answer (score 0):

Html5 audio player has events which will get triggered when the audio stops playing

```
var aud = document.getElementById("myAudio");
aud.onended = function() {
    alert("The audio has ended");
};
```

Refer [this](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_event_ended.asp) page